# why facebook block my website account?

Tags: facebook

I created a Facebook account same as my website domain address. And sent 15 friend request. Some of them answered me. And after a few days I receive some friend request and I confirm them.  I had 50 friend in my website Facebook account. Now when I log in I receive following error:

> We've received feedback that your account may not be real. Facebook is
>   a community where people share and interact using their real
>   identities. Facebook does not allow accounts that:
>
> - Pretend to be someone else
> - Use a fake name
> - Don't represent a real person
>
>   In order to regain access to your account, please complete the
>     following security check to verify your identity and help keep
>     Facebook secure.

and then show me some picture and says who they are. i don't know any of them!!
is there any way to retrieve my account

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have just created a Facebook account. If you are representing a business you need a Facebook **Page**.

Here is the [Facebook documentation about pages](https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php).